# How to add a "floor" to a model

Tags: mesh, texture-painting

I've been making my first model in blender and I was watching this tutorial on pixel textures: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yh6785-ff8k&t=4s
and I was wondering how he added the "floor" below his model in about 19:10 into the video.

[image]

Comment: from my perspective it looks like he just added a plane underneath the car, and then texture painted the little spot of blue pixels around the car.

Comment: do i add a new object for the plane? because i tried doing that and the plane is semi-transparent whenever i toggle solid view on the model

Comment: hm, that is weird?  do you mind packing your image files and sharing your file with me so I can take a closer look?  You can use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=SnsaN4Bz" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/SnsaN4Bz/)

Comment: i wanted it to look like how he did the lighting on the finished car in the video but i can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it work.

Comment: Hi this is not a forum. Please add all new information regarding your question as an [edit] to your original post so that it is readily visible to other users. There are many users who do not bother reading comments as the comments are generally considered disposable and temporary. Thanks.

Comment: the file that you gave me in that link will not open for me for some reason.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: @ETHANDAY it's a backup file (*.blend1*). You need to rename the file extension to (*.blend*) then it opens without any problem.